# How to use setTargetObjectIds and setBccAddresses in MassEmailMessage

Tags: massemailmessage

I am trying to bcc a user while sending mass email using MassEmailMessage. Can someone please help. 
Code snippet :

```
String[] bccAddress = new String[] {'contact@testcompany.com'};
Messaging.MassEmailMessage CPMail = new Messaging.MassEmailMessage();
CPMail.setTargetObjectIds(emailRecipientsList);
CPMail.setBccAddresses(bccAddress);
CPMail.setTemplateId(EmailTemplate.Id);
CPMail.setSenderDisplayName('Sam Will');
//CPMail.setBccSender(true);
CPMail.setUseSignature(false);
CPMail.setSaveAsActivity(true);
```

I get this error when I try to save it :

> Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature:
>   [Messaging.MassEmailMessage].setBccAddresses(LIST)

Answer (score 3):

`setBccAddresses` is a [Single Email Message Method](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm#apex_classes_outbound_single). Only [Base Email Message Methods](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_outbound_base.htm#apex_classes_email_outbound_base) and those methods that are specific to the [Mass Email Message Class](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_outbound_mass.htm#apex_Messaging_MassEmailMessage_methods) are permitted when sending bulk emails via Apex.

Using a template, you would need to either assign a `WhoID` to the BCC field of your template or else use the `setTargetObjectIds` method to assign other values to the template's BCC field when running your Mass Email job.

Note: As I'm certain you seem to be aware, your org would also need to have BCC Compliance Enabled.

Answer (score -1):

```
 Replace this line with below code
 String[] bccAddress = new String[] {'contact@testcompany.com'};

 List<String> bccAddress = new List<String>();
 bccAddress.add('contact@testcompany.com');
```